# how to create Metro style, windows 8 style Webpage in JSF framework

Tags: html, jsf-2

I want to create Metro style web pages. I am using JSF v2.2. I am able to include CSS for this purpose, but it only randers buttons. Other awesome graphics that can be achieved by metro is not there. 
something similar like here http://metro-webdesign.info/

Comment: have you got anything, I'm also looking the same..

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces provides a [Metro theme](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2858) which [is not free](http://primefaces.org/themes). But with such a theme, you will just be able to fake the style of Metro. You won't access to any JavaScript functionality available in the template linked in your question.

Otherwise, JSF is just a producer of HTML code. You can integrate yourself the template you linked in JSF.